# How to force update the dependency injection component in Angular: NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have two  UI component,

Tab3Page: Save the data

Tab2Page: Load the data

Tab2Page is injected to Tab3Page

I am trying to load data in Tab2Page automatically when, data is saved through Tabd3Page.

Currently, when i save the data in tab3, tab2 is not automatically updated until I refresh the page browser manually. Is there a way to force render a page like in  react as setSate()

Following is component Tab3Page

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page implements OnInit {
  pics: Picture[] = [];
  constructor(public fileservice: FileService, private tab2: Tab2Page) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ng init');
    this.pics = PICS;
  }

  saveContent(pic: Picture) {
    this.fileservice.savefile(pic);
    this.tab2.updatePics();
    this.tab2.refreshComponent();
  }
}
```

Following is component Tab2Page

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements
OnInit,
OnChanges {
  @Input() pics: Picture[];

  constructor(public fileservice:FileService, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  // constructor(public fileservice: FileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ng init');
    this.updatePics();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
    console.log('changes', changes);
  }

  async updatePics() {
    this.pics = await this.fileservice.getSavedPics();
  }

  refreshComponent() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    console.log('component refresh triggred');
  }

}
```

The data is binded in Html as following through pics variable in component Tab2Page

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let pic of pics">
  <ion-item-sliding>
    <ion-item>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="3">
          <ion-thumbnail>
            <img [src]="(pic.url | safeurl)">
          </ion-thumbnail>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="9">
          <ion-label>{{pic.name}}</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>  
    </ion-grid>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <ion-item-option>Delete</ion-item-option>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

** UPDATE
Tried to apply the suggested solution using ChangeDetectorRef
However I got following error in the browser event though the compile was success.

```
core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[IonItemOption -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[IonItemOption -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[IonItemOption -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[IonItemOption -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

As the above error suggest to add ChangeDetectorRef as provider, tried to do it in the module file. But got error again in the compile as the ChangeDetectorRef is not supported provider type.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: Tab2Page }])
  ],
  declarations: [Tab2Page, SafeurlPipe],
  providers: [ChangeDetectorRef]
})
export class Tab2PageModule {}
```

```
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
[ng]     
[ng]     ERROR in src/app/tab2/tab2.module.ts(17,15): error TS2322: Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
[ng]       Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'TypeProvider'.
[ng]         Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
[ng]     
[ng] Date: 2019-08-12T04:20:20.951Z - Hash: 99468e1aeee0ce99f6f1
[ng] 105 unchanged chunks
```

** UPDATE (FIX)
Could not get it done using the component dependency injection. However, was able to achieve same desired result using a shared data service between the component and using rxjs "Subjects" and subscribe. The process of doing it can be found on Angular documentation below. Its takes a bit to wrap head around it but is very powerful for dynamic UI rendering stuff.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

I am still a bit bugged by why I was not able to use ChangeDetectorRef in the ionic app incase I might need it in future.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `changeDetectorRef` for your problem. Your issue here is that in your `Tab3Page`, you are trying to inject `Tab2Page` and use it to call functions in `Tab2Page`. You cannot inject components directly in other components and use them. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) to see how components can interact with each other. You can use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild) to call `updatePics()`

In `Tab3Page`, remove `Tab2Page` from the contructor and add ViewChild (import it from `@angular/core`)

**tab3.page.ts**

```js
export class Tab3Page implements OnInit {
  pics: Picture[] = [];
  @ViewChild('tab2') tab2: Tab2Page;

  constructor(public fileservice: FileService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ng init');
    this.pics = PICS;
  }

  saveContent(pic: Picture) {
    this.fileservice.savefile(pic);
    this.tab2.updatePics();
  }
}
```

Add a template variable in your html so that `ViewChild` can access the component.

**tab3.page.html**

```html
<app-tab2 #tab2 [pics]="pics"></app-tab2>
```

There is one more way you can update the data. Since `pics` is an `Input` passed from `Tab3Page`, simply move `updatePics` from `Tab2Page` to `Tab3Page` and call it.

**tab3.page.ts**

```js
export class Tab3Page implements OnInit {
  pics: Picture[] = [];
  constructor(public fileservice: FileService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ng init');
    this.pics = PICS;
  }

  saveContent(pic: Picture) {
    this.fileservice.savefile(pic);
    this.updatePics();
  }

  async updatePics() {
    this.pics = await this.fileservice.getSavedPics();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for giving me few ideas. I could not use the view child idea, since these tabs were in different route and separate UI component to their respective routes.  The next suggestion would update pics data in Tab3page UI instead of Tab2Page UI. 

I had to opt another way using RxJS "Subject" which is mentioned in the angular document, https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service. Subjects and Observables are fascinating, I am still wrapping my head around it.

I wonder why I was getting runtime error with "ChangeDetectorRef" though.

Comment: My second suggestion assumes that you are passing ````pics```` from ````Tab3Page```` to ````Tab2Page```` using an ````@Input````. This way when you update ````pics```` in ````Tab3Page````, the ````@Input```` in ````Tab2Page```` would get updated as well.

Comment: I see, my bad with naming the variables same. In my usecase the two pages have different state of ``` pics ``` data. data in Tab2 is in fact subset of data in Tab3. Tab2 includes only items that the user selects from data items in Tab3.

Answer (score 0):

Inject `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
  constructor(
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {}
```

Then fire a change an event:

```
async updatePics() {
    //do something
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I got an error when using ChangeDetectorRef, looks like it has some issue with ionic angular?